# Javascript browserify bundle Error Cannot find module 'ocr-space-api-alt2'

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to bundle up my javascript object to run main.js on browser so i used browserify steps:-

1- npm install -g browserify

2- write javascript code and save it to main.js

```
var ocrSpaceApi = require('ocr-space-api-alt2')

const options =  { 
  apikey: '',
  filetype: 'png',
  verbose: true,
  url: `${__dirname}/Uff.png`
}

const getText = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await ocrSpaceApi(options)

    console.log({ result })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}

getText()
```

3- installing ocr-space-api-alt2

```
npm install ocr-space-api-alt2 also tried npm i ocr-space-api-alt2
```

at least bundle up using the command

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

but when i use the command to bundle the project i get this Error :-

> Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module 'ocr-space-api-alt2' from 'C:\xampp\htdocs\browser\main.js'
> required by C:\xampp\htdocs\browser\main.js